# Django on Heroku - add new models to postgreSQL database

Tags: django, heroku, migrate

I have an Django 2.1 / Python 3.6 application running on Heroku's hobby account. The first version of this deployment went smoothly. Now I needed to add more fields to existing models and also add additional models from my local setup (which is running very smoothly with the changes) to Heroku. I do the usual

```
git push heroku master
```

to get the new code over to Heroku. Then I do both

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

The first step gives me

```
Running python manage.py makemigrations on ⬢ hirt-family-v4... up, run.3753 (Free)
Migrations for 'users':
users/migrations/0005_auto_20190425_1452.py
- Create model XtraPhotos
- Add field phone_number to person
- Add field parent to xtraphotos
```

which is fine, but the migrate is also coming back with the message

```
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ hirt-family-v4... up, run.5929 (Free)


Operations to perform:


Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, sites, users


Running migrations:


No migrations to apply.


Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.


 Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

I tried to go step by step, meaning I add each missing field one after the other, but this also leads to the essentially same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `heroku run` to create the migration files.

1. Run `python manage.py makemigrations` locally
2. Check-in the new migration files
3. Push changes to git
4. Now, you can migrate your database with `heroku run python manage.py migrate`